# Fresh Angular 9 app with "ERROR in Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined" on Mac on "ng build"

Tags: angular, typescript

I created a new Angular 9 application on my Mac using

```
ng new demo (no routing, CSS)
cd demo
ng build
```

which fails with

```
ERROR in Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined
```

"ng version" shows

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 9.0.5
Node: 12.16.1
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 9.0.5
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.900.5 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.900.5
@angular-devkit/core            9.0.5 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics      9.0.5 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular             9.0.5 (cli-only)
@schematics/update              0.900.5 (cli-only)
rxjs                            6.5.4
typescript                      3.7.5
```

I tracked it down to

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined
    at checkUnreachable (/Users/im/tmp/demo/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:31915:31)
    at bindChildrenWorker (/Users/im/tmp/demo/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:29665:17)
    at bindChildren (/Users/im/tmp/demo/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:29621:17)
    at bind (/Users/im/tmp/demo/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:31056:21)
    at bindSourceFile (/Users/im/tmp/demo/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:29211:17)
    at Object.bindSourceFile (/Users/im/tmp/demo/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:29148:9)
    at initializeTypeChecker (/Users/im/tmp/demo/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:64532:20)
    at Object.createTypeChecker (/Users/im/tmp/demo/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:33768:9)
    at Object.getTypeChecker (/Users/im/tmp/demo/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:95767:79)
    at NgCompiler.makeCompilation (/Users/im/tmp/demo/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/core/src/compiler.js:542:42)
    at NgCompiler.<anonymous> (/Users/im/tmp/demo/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/core/src/compiler.js:191:53)
    at step (/Users/im/tmp/demo/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:139:27)
    at Object.next (/Users/im/tmp/demo/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:120:57)
    at /Users/im/tmp/demo/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:113:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (/Users/im/tmp/demo/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:109:16)
```

Which seems to happen while processing the file: /Users/im/tmp/demo/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Some version info from outside the workspace

```
# npm version

{
  demo: '0.0.0',
  npm: '6.14.2',
  ares: '1.15.0',
  brotli: '1.0.7',
  cldr: '35.1',
  http_parser: '2.9.3',
  icu: '64.2',
  llhttp: '2.0.4',
  modules: '72',
  napi: '5',
  nghttp2: '1.40.0',
  node: '12.16.1',
  openssl: '1.1.1d',
  tz: '2019c',
  unicode: '12.1',
  uv: '1.34.0',
  v8: '7.8.279.23-node.31',
  zlib: '1.2.11'
}

# ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 9.0.5
Node: 12.16.1
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 
... 
Ivy Workspace: 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.900.5
@angular-devkit/core         9.0.5
@angular-devkit/schematics   9.0.5
@schematics/angular          9.0.5
@schematics/update           0.900.5
rxjs                         6.5.3

# node -v
v12.16.1
```

Comment: Note that I'm on Windows 10. I repeated your steps to create and build the demo Angular project and it worked fine for me. I have the same version of node.js as you. Aside from the OS name, my call to "ng version" is similar to yours but mine includes a few more packages (@angular-devkit/build-optimizer, @angular-devkit/build-webpack, @ngtools/webpack, webpack).

Answer (score 3):

I found the following solution:

After `ng new demo` I checked the `package-lock.json` file and noticed that `@angular-devkit/build-angular` and `@angular-devkit/build-optimizer` are using version 3.6.4 of typescript.

After patching `package-lock.json` file and `npm install` so they are also using typescript version 3.7.5 as the app itself does it started to work.

Another solution is switching to yarn which also fixed that issue right from the start:

```
ng new demo --packageManager=yarn
```

Comment: Unfortunately using `yarn` as package manager fix nothing for me.